# How to enable trash to accept drop from cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nstableview

Is their any way to enable application to drop items into trash. Right now i m drag and drop item from NSTableView to NSTableView and NSOutlineView.

I got only single question at here [How to enable drop something on the Trash in objective-c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445849/how-to-enable-drop-something-on-the-trash-app-in-objective-c)  but dropping to trash is not happen. When i drag item outline app, i get0 for NSDragOperation.
Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    For dropping outside the location on your machine use the below DataSource methods:-
    - (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv writeRows:(NSArray*)rows toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard*)pboard
    {
        NSArray* entityArray=[yourArrayController selectedObjects];
        NSString* filename=[[[entityArray objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"fileName"]stringValue];
        [pboard setPropertyList:[NSArray arrayWithObject:filename] forType:(NSString*)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise];
        NSPoint dragPosition;
        NSRect imageLocation;

        NSEvent *theEvent   = [NSApp currentEvent];

        dragPosition = [tv convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView: nil];
        dragPosition.x -= 16;
        dragPosition.y -= 16;
        imageLocation.origin = dragPosition;
        imageLocation.size = NSMakeSize(32,32);
        [tv dragPromisedFilesOfTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"*"]
                            fromRect:imageLocation
                              source:self
                           slideBack:YES
                               event:theEvent];
        return YES;
    }

    //For Enabled the Dropping and Extracting the File Path. This method will give you exact path
    - (NSArray *)namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination
    {
        NSString *str=[dropDestination path];
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
        NSMutableArray  *rootDraggedItemsNames = nil;
        return rootDraggedItemsNames;
    }

    //When Drag Files accepted to the Destination, then it Start Download the Files. This will accept the file drops on the destination
    - (void)draggedImage:(NSImage *)anImage endedAt:(NSPoint)aPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation
    {
        [[NSPasteboard pasteboardWithName:NSDragPboard] declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise] owner:self];
    }

    The below method is for registering the file promises

   -(void)setAcceptDrops:(BOOL)acceptDrops
{
    if (acceptDrops)
    {
        [tableView registerForDraggedTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString*)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise, nil]];
        [tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationCopy forLocal:NO];

    }
    else
    {
        [tableView registerForDraggedTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil]];
        [tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationCopy forLocal:NO];
    }
}

-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [self setAcceptDrops:YES];
}

Hope it helps:)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and sorry for late reply by me. i try this code to drag and drop from app to trash but if i drop file image on trash icon on desktop,  - (NSArray *)namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination method is not called. And if i stay on trash icon and wait for opening the trash window, above method is called but trash is not accepting drop of file. Please suggest me more on this.

Comment: Is it possible that if i drag item outside app then dragged row from table converted to image, so that trash accept it because dragged image method is called only when dragging an image ?

Comment: If you want to drop the image on to trash then try below:-    - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{
    NSString *imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImageName" ofType:@"tiff"];
    NSImage *photoImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:imageName];
    [imv setImage:photoImage];
} -(void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{NSString *imageName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourImageName" ofType:@"tiff"];
 [self dragFile:imageName fromRect:NSMakeRect(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) slideBack:YES event:theEvent];} As it is partially impelemented. Pls do it acc. yo req.

Comment: Can i manage to drop a table row to trash ? and from image i means is this method  - (void)draggedImage:(NSImage *)anImage endedAt:(NSPoint)aPoint operation:(NSDragOperation)operation
    {

Answer (score 0):

While trying to solve a different problem - dragging custom items to the trash and using `namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination` I found that even though the dragged item(s) disappear like the drag worked `namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination` was never called. To get around this you can implement:

```
-(void)draggedImage:(NSImage *)anImage
             endedAt:(NSPoint)aPoint
           operation:(NSDragOperation)operation
```

and check the operation for `NSDragOperationDelete`